# Nodejs : How to use variable from a router in another router

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an `Express` server where I separate routes into two independant files `routesA.js` and `routesB.js`

Here is `routesA.js` :

```
const aRoutes = (app, fs) => {
    const dataPath = 'example';
};

module.exports = aRoutes;
```

`routesB.js` :

```
const aRoutes = require('./routesA');

const bRoutes = (app, fs) => {
    console.log(aRoutes.dataPath);//-> undefined
};

module.exports = bRoutes;
```

I would like to read the variable `dataPath` inside `bRoutes`.

How to do this properly?

Comment: So why don't you return `dataPath` from `aRoutes`?

Comment: it is already exported at the end of the file with `module.exports = aRoutes;`

Comment: So you're saying you can't make changes to `aRoutes`? That's important to know for this question. Might want to include that in the question.

Comment: what changes are you refering to ?

Comment: You have to specify that the `routesA.js` file cannot be changed for people to help you. This changes the possible solution fundamentally.

Comment: The answer to your question is this: You do not have access to variables inside a function.

Comment: again, what changes are you refering to ? i never said you can't change `routesA.js`. I made the effort to make the problem as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `aRoutes.dataPath` as if it's an object when it's actually a function. If you want to return the `dataPath` value from `aRoutes` then you need to fix your code.

routesA.js

```
const aRoutes = (app, fs) => {
    const dataPath = 'example';
    return dataPath;
};

module.exports = aRoutes;
```

routesB.js :

```
const aRoutes = require('./routesA');

const bRoutes = (app, fs) => {
    console.log(aRoutes()); // You're calling the function and console logging the value
};

module.exports = bRoutes;
```

Comment: I can't just call `aRoutes()` to get a variable, as I mentioned these files are part of a server and each one has many routes inside of it. dataPath is a `const` not a function

Comment: Your question was "how to properly read the value of dataPath inside bRoutes" This is how you would read the value of dataPath from bRoutes. You can assign dataPath to a variable in your bRoutes using `const dataPath = aRoutes();`

Comment: no it does not work, i have tried it! even if it worked i can't do it this way, you understand that my question was a simplified case, in the real world as I explained to you, calling aRoute() would mean calling all routes inside of it which will crash my server.

Comment: I think you have your routes are set up wrong or your question isn't clear. Have a read through the Express docs. They're very helpful and clear. Have a read through routes and controllers. gl

Comment: This isn't helping me. i've already did it thousand times, i've been trying to solve this problem this whole day, their documentation is actually not clear.